# Выбор интерпретатора питона в командной строке

Tags: python, pip, интерпретатор

У меня на компьютере установлено 2 интерпретатора питона: обычный и анакондовский. pip в командной строке устанавливает библиотеки на анакондовский интерпретатор, однако если запускать питоновский файл, то он работает с обычным компилятором питона и соответственно не видит установленных библиотек. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробуйте запускать через `python main.py`.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, заработало)

Comment: У меня тоже два питона: системный (для мака и python  3.7) — `python3` для третьего, `python` — для второго, `pip3` — для третьего, `pip` — для второго.